# Reproducing a nested not in statement through a join statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm learning T-SQL via the AdventureWorks 2012 database in SQL Server 2014 Express, doing some exercises.  In one of the exercises, I'm asked to display the `productid` and `name` for any products that have not been ordered (ie the `productid` is not found in the `sales.salesorderdetail` table).  Fairly straightforward, I used a nested `not in` statement below and this is the correct answer, returning 238 rows.

```
select p.productid
, p.name
from production.product p
where p.productid not in
(select sod.productid
from sales.salesorderdetail sod
where sod.productid is not null)
order by p.productid;
```

For my own learning purposes, I'm trying to reproduce this by using a join statement instead. My attempt is below, however it comes up with an incorrect result, returning all of the `productid`'s from the above queries plus many more, for 504 rows.

```
select distinct p.productid
, p.name
from production.product p
inner join sales.salesorderdetail sod on sod.productid <> p.productid
order by p.productid;
```

Why doesn't joining on `sod.productid <> p.productid` produce the same result as my `not in` query?  Because I'm trying this on my own there's no answer in the workbook I can check against.  Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it fails is that you'll match any row where the productids doesn't match which really is not what you want. If you add `, p.ProductID, sod.ProductID` to the select you'll see what's happening more clearly.

The "correct" way to do this using a join is to use a `left join` and filter out rows with null values:

```
select p.productid, p.name
from production.product p
left join sales.salesorderdetail sod on sod.productid = p.productid
where sod.ProductID is null
order by p.productid;
```

Comment: Wow, I should have known this, can't believe I didn't see this.  Sorry for the glaring oversight, and thanks for the clear explanation.

Comment: @JulianDrago Also, in your original query `where sod.productid is not null` in the subquery serves no purpose and can be removed.